# how do i know when location.reload() finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i have a frame that i want to reload, resetting all values and content of the page, but the root page continues with running scripts.  The issue with that is that in the time it takes for the page to reload, requests are sent to the pages javascript, causing errors as resources are not loaded.

```
top.document.getElementById("designer").contentWindow.location.reload()
top.document.getElementById("designer").contentWindow.getCSS()
```

So as you can see here, the page might not be reloaded in time, so how would i resolve this?

is there a way to pause javascript execution until *location.reload()* returns true or something?

Comment: i guess i could do is set up an event listener on the iframe until document.ready sends an ACK to continue?

Comment: assuming this isn't cross-domain, just add a listener for the `load` event.

Comment: do you have a sample by chance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up `onload` handler for your iframe so that your `reload` doesnt trigger

Sample code:-

```
function Test() {

    iframe = document.getElementById('ABCD');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        location.reload(true);
    }
    //.... 
}
```

or if you want to add some time delay then try like this:-

```
function Test() {
    iframe = document.getElementById('ABCD');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {location.reload(true)}, 5000);
    }
    //....
}
```

Comment: @Fallenreaper:- Yes that would do. And I have tried to add a sample code for your reference. Hope that helps!!!

Comment: i feel this might now quite do what i want.  trying to interpret the code a bit.  my goal is to do something like:  set an event handler for the iframe.  Reload the iframe, pause execution of javascript until onload finishes, then then continue?

Comment: Yes it would work for you!!! P.S. And dont forget to accept it as an answer if it helped you!! :)

Comment: @Fallenreaper a common mistake is to try to pause execution of JavaScript, which is impossible. What you must do instead is break your code into 2 parts; before the delay and after the delay. Put the code which should run after the delay into the function which you set as the event handler.

Comment: If i have it modular enough, it shouldnt be too bad.  Ill take a look.  Waiting for some servers to spin up and then i will be testing this answer and then giving it the offocial thumbs up! :)